# Procesar un TXT a PRN con Python

Tags: python

Tengo varios archivos txt con informacion de algunos pagos en txt separados por saltos de linea y barras inclinadas. lo que tengo es esto:

{

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


# Importacion de la libreria necesaria
import re

#Apertura de archivo
fname = raw_input(": >")
fopen = open(fname) 


#Se definen 3 listas, una para cada columna
col1 = list()
col2 = list()
col3 = list()

#Edicion del texto para cada campo

for i in fopen:
    col = re.findall('[0-9]+', i)
    col1.append(col[0].lstrip('0'))
    col2.append(col[1].lstrip('0'))
    decimal = col[2] + "." + col[3]
    col3.append(decimal)
fopen.close()

#Impresion de archivo PRN
cont = 0
while cont < len(col1):
   prn = col1[cont] + " " + col2[cont] + " " + col3[cont] + "\n"
   print prn
   cont = cont + 1 
   fwrite.write(prn)
```

}

El texto esta como yo quiero, lo que quisera hacer es guardar un archivo PRN (texto con espacios con una longitud maxima de 240 caracteres por linea) directamente con python con el formato mencionado.

{

```
   3830762       403  2620.39
   3830762       404  2620.39
   3830762       216  3226.30
   3975560       217  1329.61
   3975560       210  2124.30
   3975560       403  3351.33
   3975560       404  3351.33
   4068493       403  2922.72
   4068493       404  2922.72
   4378091       210  1028.15
   4378091       403  2337.48
   4378091       404  2337.48
   4404173       216  1001.80
   4527545       403  2227.71
   4527545       404  2227.71
   4975179       216   824.10
   4975179       403  2254.68
   4975179       404  2254.68
   5048485       403  2643.13
   5048485       404  2643.13
   5060558       403  3516.09
   5060558       404  3516.09
   5181225       403  3498.39
   5181225       404  3498.39
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando la forma más simple y segura de salvar un archivo:

```
with open("archivo.prn", "w") as file
   while cont < len(col1):
      prn = col1[cont] + " " + col2[cont] + " " + col3[cont] + "\n"
      print prn
      cont = cont + 1 
      file.write(prn)
```

Hacemos uso de lo que se conoce como [`context managers`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) una construcción propia de Python que en el caso de los archivos permite cerrarlos automáticamente, una vez finalizado todo el bloque de instrucciones que contiene,  además de proveer una forma más limpia y segura de finalizar en caso de error.

Por otro lado, reescribiendo tu código con [`context managers`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) para la lectura y escritura y de una forma más "pythonica", podría quedar todo así:

```
import re

fname = raw_input(": >")
with open("{0}.prn".format(fname), "w") as out_file:
    with open(fname, "r") as in_file:
        for linea in in_file.readlines():
            col = re.findall('[0-9]+', linea)
            out = "{0} {1} {2}.{3}\n".format(col[0].lstrip('0'), col[1].lstrip('0'), col[2], col[3])
            out_file.write(out)
```

Haciendo `in_file.readlines()`, leemos todas las líneas del archivo y por cada una, vamos haciendo el proceso y salvándola inmediatamente, con esto reducimos bastante la lógica. Como puedes ver al usar los `context manager` no necesitamos hacer el `close` habitual.

Comment: WOW! pues en un momento pensé utilizar las listas para tener el codigo mas facil. pero esta es la mas "elegante". mil gracias de verdad.

Comment: aunque tengo una duda adicional:¿como hacer para que los campos tengan 30 caracteres de espacio maximo?  en el .format?

Comment: @BryanUseche: una forma, por ejemplo si buscas alinear un campo a la derecha con espacios sería algo así: `"{0:>30}".format(numero)`, a la izquierda sería usando `"<"` o bien puedes agregar fijos los espacios entre cada dato `"{0}_________________{1}".format(n1, n2)` (reemplaza los `_` por espacios).

Comment: Excelente, gracias por el dato.